# Change aria-expanded="true" to false on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

This is the button that triggers the side menu open / close on Moodle boost theme. I am trying to keep the menu hidden by default on page load.

So, I need to set  `<button aria-expanded="true"` to  `<button aria-expanded="false"` on page load. However, all the Javascript snippets I have tried need the element to have an 'Id' or a 'Name'; and this button has neither.

**Question :** How to I change the `<button aria-expanded="true"` to  `<button aria-expanded="false"` on page load - without changing the source code of Moodle ?

```
<button aria-expanded="true" 
aria-controls="nav-drawer" 
type="button" 
class="btn nav-link float-sm-left mr-1 btn-secondary" 
data-action="toggle-drawer" 
data-side="left" 
data-preference="drawer-open-nav">
<i class="icon fa fa-bars fa-fw " 
aria-hidden="true" aria-label="">
</i>
<span class="sr-only">Side panel</span>
</button>
```

**Tried so far :** I have searched if someone has done this already. Could not find anything. Tried several onload Javascript snippets, but nothing worked. Will appreciate some guidance & help.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for the icon or a more specific element since the icon can be used more than once (or select it with `:nth-child`) and look up the previous element with jQuery. Then change the attribute of the button accordingly.

```
$('.icon fa fa-bars fa-fw').prev().attr("aria-expanded","false");
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the link to my [codepen solution](https://codepen.io/CaptainTeemo/pen/VEYMQj) written in pure javascript and here is the explanation:

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button"), dropdownBtn;

window.onload = function(){
    for (var i=0; i<btn.length; i++) {
        if(btn[i].getAttribute("data-action") == "toggle-drawer") {
            console.log(btn[i]);
            btn[i].setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Since you don't have any unique class or id o your button so went ahead and assumed that any one of the `data-attribute` on your button is unique (in this case `data-action`). Also, I assumed that your HTML document has many buttons hence I selected all the buttons and then iterated all over them to find the `data-action` attribute and as soon as I found it I set its `aria-expanded` value to `false` and exited the loop.

And all these happened while the document is loading.